# How do I reset git changes before commit?

Tags: git

I have changed few files and I haven't commit anything yet. Why I `git diff` I can see that few files are changed. I want to roll back to the latest commit.

Answer (score 2):

In the `git status` screen, git tells you what to do to remove changes to a file.  If the files are staged for a commit, you will need to do `git reset HEAD <file>` to unstage.  You can reset all the files by just using `git reset`.  This will unstage the files and then you can do `git checkout -- <file>` to get back the specific files to the original state.

You can also do it all in one command with `git reset --hard` this sets your repo to the latest commit that the branch is at.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

will revert a file back to the last commit

Answer (score 0):

You should be able rollback using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```